# How to create a Communication Site

Tags: modern-experience, site, team-sites, communication-site

I have a client who built a Team site, but realized that she actually wants a Communication site because of the placement of the Navigation links.  I can't find where to create this new site.  I've followed a couple guides I found online, but this is what I see:

I first click on the highlighted portion, then click on SharePoint.

[image]

Then I only see an option to Create a News Post:

[image]

Could someone please let me know how I can create a communication site?  I'm a site owner with full control...so I don't know if it's a permissions issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be a SharePoint Administrator to create a Communication Site as a Site Collection. Please check your access.

If you have the access, then follow the below steps to create a Communication Site,

- Navigate to Sharepoint page https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx
- Click **Create Site** Link
  [image]
- Select Communication Site box from the Panel
  [image]
- Then enter the details and create a site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this does help.  So I need to be an Administrator to create a new site?  Because I can currently only create a News Post.